# req.body is not appearing in postman

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

```
I was sending the post request in raw and json format...
```

[this is the header configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBkOo.png)

```
So heres the code:

//app.js

const port =  process.env.PORT || 3000;
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const jsonParser = require('body-parser').json;
const routes = require('./routes/routes.js');


app.use(jsonParser());

app.use("/questions", routes);

//All routine stuff I'd say...

app.listen(port,(err)=>{
    if (!err)
            {console.log(`The express server is running at http://localhost:${port}`)}
});
//routes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//GET /questions
//return all the questions from the db
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({response: "You sent me a get request"}); 
});

//POST /questions
//Route for creating questions
router.post("/", function(req, res){
    res.json({
        response: "you sent me a POST request",
        body: req.body

    });
});




module.exports = router;
```

[this is the error i get after the post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNqSh.png)

This is the error i keep getting.. I'm clueless as to how I should fix it.. I just cant get req.body to appear in Postman... Im not sure if I missed anything or didnt add anything or maybe threw a spanner in the gears... Any help is appreciated.

```
//The error is as following
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\Restful\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at C:\Restful\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Restful\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Restful\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Restful\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
```

Comment: If it wasn't application/json, the json bodyparser wouldn't be handling it, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your request body as specified in the screenshot and this will work as the object keys need to be string: [image: Postman Request body]

Comment: thanks a lot ashish. i was actually sending the json into bson format cause i was recently working with mongo. such a small mistake, thanks a lot i was stuck for a day now..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to solve your problem:

```
let bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `req.body` may be an error string, which can cause the `jsonParser` to freak out. Add a `console.log(req.body)` before your `res.json` call for your `router.post` to see what the value actually is. That should give you more info into why it's failing to parse.

Edit: Are you setting your `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in your request from Postman?

Comment: Check Ashish answer. You aren't sending valid json, because it needs the keys to be wrapped in quotes as well. Which lines up with the error.

Comment: I love getting downvoted because context was added to the question after the fact that made my answer seem obvious...